# Python - Function body from String to Equation

Tags: python, string, list, function

I am trying to define a function from a list of strings containing parameters and expression :

`['input1', 'input2', 'output1', 'output1 = input1 + input2']`

The format expected is the following :

```
def function(input1, input2):
   output1 = input1 + input2
   return output1
```

The aim is therefore to define a function automatically from a list.

I used the Python function 'eval()' to make the string expression as an equation :

```
def function (??, ??)
     eval('output1 = input1 + input2')
```

**The problem encoutered** is with parameters.

How should I include parameters evaluation (inputs, outputs) so there is no error like `'input1' is not defined` ?
By evaluating parameters before evaluating expression ? By using another function that eval() ?

**PS**: If possible no float values should be assigned to variables so the equation remains literal.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: is the home to end with a global variable `output1` with some value? Have you check the different behavior between `exec()` and `eval()`?  Do you control all the input such that no one will inject something "bad"?

Comment: I do not know why you need to do this but i strongly advise against it. dynamically defining functions at runtime will only get you trouble. Why not statically define as much functions as you need in your code ?